# Webdriver Selenium do not get all the information in the table

Tags: c#, html, selenium, webdriver

I am getting the data of product information according to the link: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005NASSRO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005NASSRO), the information needing to get the data is like in the picture:

[image]

This my code

```html
_webDriver.Url = $"https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005NASSRO";

var hasUpc = _webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='bissProductSpecification_feature_div']/div[@class='a-section a-spacing-large pzr-features-containers']/div/div/div/div/table[@id='product-specification-table']/tbody/tr"), 30);
                    string ean = "";
                    string mpn = "";
                    foreach (var element in hasUpc)
                    {
                        string el = element.FindElement(By.XPath("th")).Text;
                        Console.WriteLine(el);
                        if (element.FindElement(By.XPath("th")).Text.Trim().Equals("UPC") || element.FindElement(By.XPath("th")).Text.Trim().Equals("Global Trade Identification Number"))
                        {
                            upc = element.FindElement(By.XPath("td")).Text.Trim();
                        }
                        if (element.FindElement(By.XPath("th")).Text.Trim().Equals("Ean"))
                        {
                            ean = element.FindElement(By.XPath("td")).Text.Trim();
                        }
                        if (element.FindElement(By.XPath("th")).Text.Trim().Equals("Model Number"))
                        {
                            mpn = element.FindElement(By.XPath("td")).Text.Trim();
                        }
                    }
```

And this result:

[image: link of image]

Data in source of html still completely returns the value in the table. I don't know if it's right.

Comment: Hi bapcun! Welcome to StackOverflow, I notice you are a new contributor! I would suggest improving the chances of your question being answered by providing the actual code shared as image in a text format\,

Comment: @tin: Thank you very much, I will learn from experience next time

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about C#, It can be done using python easily

here is the code for the table

```
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005NASSRO'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\seleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe') #Your chrome driver path

getr = browser.get(url)
srcc = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)
names = srcc.xpath('//table[@id="product-specification-table"]//tbody//tr//th//text()')
values = srcc.xpath('//table[@id="product-specification-table"]//tbody//tr//td//text()')

for (name, value) in zip(names, values):
    name = name.strip()
    value = value.strip()
    print(name, value, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, from your code, I tried using the page_source method for this. This is also a way for me to continue my work

Answer (score 0):

Using java. This will output only the 2 column.

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005NASSRO");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'See more')]")).click();
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[id*=product-specification-table]  tbody tr td"));

int i = 0;
for(WebElement row : list) {
    System.out.println(row.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thank Abraham Cantillo, we must click 'See more' to expand all table, I can get all the values in the table